# Reading a number from a multi-line txt document in c++

Tags: c++, variables, casting, io, ifstream

I'm making a program, and have a .txt file that i need to read from, and get commands from. the text document looks like:

```
U
R
F 10
D
F 13
Q
```

and i need to get the numbers out of it. the way im reading the file is from an `ifstream` object named `instream`. currently i'm using

```
while(instream.get(charVariable)){
    switch(charVariable){
    case 'F': //do the forward command
       break;
    ...
    }
}
```

The forward command needs to take that line, which it does, and it needs to read the `F`, skip the space, and get the whole number into an `int` variable. I'm fairly new to c++, so i need help doing that.... how would i get the number, read into a single char variable, into an integer variable? any help would be great! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`streams` move as you read from them. That means when you have read `F` from the stream then the next input is the `integer`. And since they work on formatted input the stream will skip the white space for you  when you use  `>>`

```
while(instream >> charVariable)){
    switch(charVariable){
    case 'F': //do the forward command
       int nr;
       instream >> nr;
       // do something with number.
       break;
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: so, what is iss, nr, and numbers?

Comment: @wbAnon `iss` is just a typo, `nr` is an `int`, and `numbers` is a `vector` of ints but I think you don't need to collect the numbers or do you?

Comment: i do, the number is the amount of moving forward

Comment: @wbAnon what do you mean exactly by moving forward?

Comment: nvm, its fine. i took what you did and changed it a bit, and now it works like a charm! thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Basically there is no huge difference between filestreams and i/o streams. You can do the following:

```
while(!instream.eof())
{
    char command;
    instream >> command;
    switch(command)
    {
        case 'F':
            int F_value;
            instream >> F_value;
            forward(F_value);
            break;

        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the numbers used can be greater than one character (ie "10" is two chars), it would be best to just use a regular integer variable.

```
int n;
...
instream >> n; //if your switch statement is working this goes inside the 'F' case
```

Then you can do what you wish with n (before you read the next integer into n).